# Rendering two pages with same content in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

The scenario for this is: After I displayed the product's information in the main page. There is a two buttons(stock in and stock out), if I click the stock in it will appear the stock in page with the product's information, same with stock out if I click it also. I hope someone can help me. I am new to NodeJS please bear with me hehe

```
exports.getFlowerViewDetails = (req,res,next) => {

    
    const stocks = Stocks.findById(req.params.stockID);
    res.render('stock-in', {st: stocks[0]});
    res.render('stock-out', {st: stocks[0]});
   
    // render detail page
}
```

```
    <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.flowerName%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
          <label for="inputContactNo" class="col-form-label">Contact No.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.quantity%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
          <label for="inputDate" class="col-form-label">Pick-up Date</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.pricePieces%>
      </div>

      <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="inputStatus" class="col-form-label">Status</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.remarks%>
      </div>
```

```
<h1>STOCK OUT</h1>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.flowerName%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
          <label for="inputContactNo" class="col-form-label">Contact No.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.quantity%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
          <label for="inputDate" class="col-form-label">Pick-up Date</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.pricePieces%>
      </div>

      <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="inputStatus" class="col-form-label">Status</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= st.remarks%>
      </div>
```

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: you can't set two responses as you have now:

`res.render('stock-in', {st: stocks[0]});`
`res.render('stock-out', {st: stocks[0]});`

remove one of them, create another method to return the other one

Comment: Your error is because you are calling res.render multiple times. You need to first define 2 separate routes for 2 pages and then create separate middleware functions which will call res.render only for that route.